# Excel Formula If user input data on column A, column B show current date and time

Tags: excel, datetime, if-statement

[Excel Formula Problem] If user input data on column A, column B show current date and time

Comment: What have you tried yet. Can you show anything? maybe a printscreen or something?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
=IF(A1<>"",TEXT(NOW(),"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

In **B1** enter:

```
=IF(A1="","",NOW())
```

and format **B1** as DateTime.

**B1** will then display the **current** date/time.  To capture the **date/time of entry** you would use an Event Macro.

**EDIT#1**

To capture the date/time of entry, insert the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Range("A:A"))
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each r In rng
        With r.Offset(0, 1)
            .Value = Now
            .NumberFormat = "dd mmmm yyyy hh:mm:ss"
        End With
    Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as **.xlsm** rather than **.xlsx**

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: And now I would like to know why..
when i input data on other column, the column will auto refresh?
How to fix it if i want to keep the "current time" for record